# Get Width and Height of Windows Form C# After user clicks on Restore

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

I want to get the exact width and height of the windows form. Initially I set this 1024*768 but when user clicks on restore button its width may vary according to User machine screen resolution. So how can i get the exact height and width of the form when user maximized the window.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Resize` event. This event occurs when user resizes the form in any way, whether through Maximize/Restore buttons, or manually dragging the edges of the form. Therein you can use `Form.ClientRectangle` or `Form.Size` properties to get the exact width and height of your form after it is resized.